# missing data in time series

Tags: time-series, missing-data

As im so new to this field and im trying to explore the data for a time series, and find the missing values and count them and study a distribution of their length and fill in these gaps, the thing is i have, let's say 10 file.txt and for each file i have 2 columns as follows:

C1     C2

944    0

920    1

920    2

928    3

912    7

920    8

920    9

880    10

888    11

920    12

944    13

and so on... lets say till 100 and not necessarily the 10 files have the same number of observations.

so here for example the missing values and not necessarily appears in all files that i have, missing value are: 4,5 and 6 in C2 and the corresponding 1st column C1(measured in milliseconds, so the value of 928ms is not a time neighbor of 912ms). So i want to find those gaps(the total missing values in all 10 files) and show a histogram of their lengths.

i wrote a piece of code in R, but the problem is that i don't get the exact total number that i should have for the missing values.

```
path = "files path"

out.file<-data.frame(TS = 0, Index = 0, File = '')

file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".txt")

for(i in 1:length(file.names)){

   file <- cbind(read.table(file.names[i],
                            header=F, 
                            sep ="\t", 
                            stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
                 file.names[i])

   colnames(file) <- c('TS', 'Index', 'File')

   out.file <- rbind(out.file, file)

}

d = dim(out.file)[1]

misDa = 0

for(i in 2:(d-1)){

  if(abs(out.file$Index[i]-out.file$Index[i+1]) > 1)

  misDa = misDa+1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give specific hints without having a more extensive example of your data that contains some of the actual NAs.

If you are using R (like it seems) the `naniar` and the `imputeTS` packages offer nice functions for missing data visualizations.

Some examples from the `naniar` package, which is especially good for multivariate data ([more plot examples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/getting-started-w-naniar.html)):

[image]

[image]

Some examples from the `imputeTS` package, which is especially good for time series data ([additional plot examples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/vignettes/gallery_visualizations.html)):

[image]

[image]